# SciPy Conjugate Gradient Optimisation not invoking callback method after each iteration

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, scipy, theano

I followed the tutorial [here](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_cg.py) in order to implement Logistic Regression using theano. The aforementioned tutorial uses SciPy's `fmin_cg` optimisation procedure. Among the important argument to the aforementioned function are: `f` the object/cost function to be minimised, `x0` a user supplied initial guess of the parameters, `fprime` a function which provides the derivative of the function `f` at `x` and `callback` an optional user-supplied function, called after each iteration.

The training function is defined as follows:

```
# creates a function that computes the average cost on the training set
def train_fn(theta_value):
    classifier.theta.set_value(theta_value, borrow=True)
    train_losses = [batch_cost(i * batch_size)
                    for i in xrange(n_train_batches)]
    return numpy.mean(train_losses)
```

What the above code does, is basically go through all the minibatches in the training dataset, for each minibatch calculate the average batch cost (i.e. the average of the cost function applied to each of the training samples in the minibatch) and averages the cost over all the batches. It might be worth pointing out that the cost for each individual batch is calculated by `batch_cost` -- a theano function.

To me, it seems that the `callback` function is being called arbitrarily, and not after every iteration as the documentation in SciPy claims.

Here is the output I received after modifying `train_fn` and `callback` by adding "train" and "callback" prints respectively.

```
... training the model
train
train
train
callback
validation error 29.989583 %
train
callback
validation error 24.437500 %
train
callback
validation error 20.760417 %
train
callback
validation error 16.937500 %
train
callback
validation error 14.270833 %
train
callback
validation error 14.156250 %
train
callback
validation error 13.177083 %
train
callback
validation error 12.270833 %
train
train
callback
validation error 11.697917 %
train
callback
validation error 11.531250 %
```

My question is, since each call to `train_fn` is indeed a training epoch, how do I change the behaviour, so that a call to `callback` is invoked after `train_fn`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each call to `train_fn` is *not* necessarily a single training epoch. I'm not exactly sure how `fmin_cg` is implemented, but in general, [conjugate gradient methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) may call the cost or gradient function more than once per minimziation step. This is (as far as I understand it) required sometimes to find the conjugate vector relative to the previous step taken.<sup>1</sup>

So your callback is being called every time `fmin_cg` takes a *step*. If you need a function to be called every time the cost or gradient function is called, you can just put the call inside the relevant function.

<sup>1. Edit: At least when they are *nonlinear* methods, as [`fmin_cg`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cg.html) is. The wikipedia page suggests that vanilla conjugate gradient (CG) methods may not require multiple calls, but I think they aren't as suitable for optimizing nonlinear functions. The CG code that I've seen -- which I guess must have been for nonlinear CG -- definitely involved at least one line search per step. That could certainly call for multiple evaluations of the gradient function.</sup>